# Error, replacement has n rows while data has m

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a simple model on a PCA transformed dataset. However, when I attempt to map `train.pca['outcome'] = train.df[,'outcome']` I get the error

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "outcome", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 500 rows, data has 32000
```

The complete code up to the error is below.

```
library(xgboost)
library(readr)
library(caret)


train.raw = read.csv("file", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
drop = c('column')
train.df = train.raw[, !(names(train.raw) %in% drop)]
train.df[,'outcome'] = as.factor(train.df[,'outcome'])

train.c1 = subset(train.df ,  outcome == 1)
train.c0 = subset(train.df ,  outcome == 0)


fit.pca = prcomp(train.df[,1:100], retx = TRUE, center = T, scale = T)
summary(fit.pca)

train.pca = data.frame(fit.pca$x)
train.pca = train.pca[,1:20]
train.pca['outcome'] = train.df[,'outcome']
```

I imagine this has something to do with how I'm subsetting the data but I'm not sure what. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `train.pca = as.data.frame(train.pca)` and retry

Comment: @missuse Thanks I think I see what the problem is now, I need to check the data set more carefully as I'm now getting the error: `Error in as.data.frame.default(fit.pca) : cannot coerce class ""prcomp"" to a data.frame`

Comment: sorry my mistake. I meant `train.pca = data.frame(fit.pca$x)` but you already have that line, I missed it. I can not replicate the problem with `iris` data set:`data(iris); z = prcomp(iris[,1:4])$x; z = data.frame(z); z['outcome'] = iris$Species` works